# Why don't join queries hit Hibernate second-level cache?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I have some confusion regarding Hibernate second-level cache.Of what I have read,Hibernate second-level cache stores only the ids and is beneficial only in case of lookup by id queries.Why does hibernate not use cache in case of a join where the ids of both the tables on which the the join is done is cached?
I ran a program to test this and found that with the cache enabled the join queries took more time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second-level cache caches the state of entities, indexed by ID. But it's a cache. It only stores *some* of the entities (the most recently used, typically).

So, even if Hibernate could parse the query, analyze it, notice that it only contains restrictions on entity IDs, it can't use its cache to bypass the database, since it doesn't know if all the entities that would be returned by the database are in the cache or aren't. So it doesn't do all that, and simply executes the query, as any other query.

What you can do though is to configure a query cache. that would make it cache the IDs of the entities returned by a previously executed query. In that case, the second execution of the same query (with the same arguments) would be bypassed, the IDs would be returned from the query cache, and the states would be loaded from the second level cache.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!I am looking at a scenario where the join queries would have different arguments.In this cache,as I understand,won't be of any help right?